# anonymous list to DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wrote this code in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(m => new { Id = m.Id, m.Name, m.LastName }));
    return View();
}
```

and in the view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Customer.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but in the browser I get this result in dropdown

[image: ResultPic]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the controller code to this

```
        ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Id.ToString(), Text = m.Name + " " + m.LastName }), "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Crea a ViewModel:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

On Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CreateViewModel();
    model.Customers = db.Customers.TolIst();

    return View(model);
}
```

On View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Selected.Id, new SelectList(
          Model.Customers,
          "Id",
          "Name",
          Model.SelectedId))
```

Comment: ,thank you for your answer,but i dont want create model,it possible do this job like my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not passing member names for the value and text of the select list. By default, it will try to use members named `Value` and `Text`, respectively, which your anonymous object does not have. Failing that, then, it simply calls `ToString` on each item in the list, and uses that for both the value and text, which of course is what's happening here.

Therefore, the simplest fix is to simply pass strings representing the members to use for the value and text params:

```
ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(m => new { Id = m.Id, m.Name, m.LastName }), "Id", "Name");
```

However, the better approach is to not select into an anonymous object at all and use `SelectListItem` instead:

```
ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Id.ToString(), Text = m.Name + " " + m.LastName }));
```

You'll notice this also gives you the ability to concat the `Name` and `LastName` values together, whereas the other approach only allows you to select one or the other.

Comment: thak you for your answer i change controller code to ViewBag.CustomerList = new SelectList(db.Customers.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Id.ToString(), Text = m.Name + " " + m.LastName })); but in result i get System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem in option,how i can fixed this ?

Comment: Interesting. I could've sworn `SelectList` handled everything correctly when it's passed an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, but apparently not. You can either 1) do something like `new SelectList(..., "Value", "Text")` or 2) don't bother to create a `SelectList` at all and just pass the result of the `Select` directly to the `Html.DropDownListFor` call. Razor will handle creating the `SelectList` automatically.